# problem with - TypeError: XXX is not a function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am having an issue with calling a parent function:

> Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: self.$parent.testAddCompontnet222 is not a function"

So i have setup a test function (method) in the following file called `testAddCompontnet222()`

parent file: **PageAdd.vue**

```
<template>
    <b-container>
        <b-container>
            testVar2: (( {{ testVar2 }} ))
            <b-button @click="testAddCompontnet222();">Add Test 2</b-button>
            <SingleBlockTemplate v-if="componentTypeSelected == 1"></SingleBlockTemplate>
            <TripleBlockTemplate v-if="componentTypeSelected == 2"></TripleBlockTemplate>
        </b-container>                    
    </b-container>
</template>


<script>
    import axios from 'axios';
    import SingleBlockTemplate from './component_templates/SingleBlockTemplate.vue';
    import TripleBlockTemplate from './component_templates/TripleBlockTemplate.vue';
    import ComponentAddForm from './ComponentAddForm.vue';
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                title: 'Case Studies',
                excerpt: 'some text here for reference',
                slug: 'unique',
                meta_title: 'title for search engines (should be the same as the page title)',
                meta_description: 'meta descriptions for search engines',
                meta_keywords: 'keywords',
                order: '1',
                status: '1',
                showAddComponentForm: false,
                error: false,
                errors: {},

                testVar2: '2',

                newContentData: {},

                componentTypeSelected: '2',
                componentTypes: {},
                componentList: {}
            };
        },
        mounted: function () {
            this.getComponentTypes();
            //this.componentTypeToCreate =
        },

        methods: {
            testAddCompontnet222(){
                this.testVar2 = '222!';
                console.log("test 222222!")
            },
            addPage(){
                axios({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: this.$appAPI+'/twg-cms/page',
                    data: {
                        title: this.title,
                        excerpt: this.excerpt,
                        slug: this.slug,
                        meta_title: this.meta_title,
                        meta_description: this.meta_description,
                        meta_keywords: this.meta_keywords,
                        order: this.order,
                        status: this.status
                    }

                }).then(response => {
                    console.log(response.data)
                }).catch(e => {
                    console.log(e)
                    this.errors.push(e)
                });
            },
            getComponentTypes(){
                axios.get(this.$appAPI+`/twg-cms/component_types`)
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.componentTypes = response.data.data;
                    })
                    .catch(() => {
                        console.log('handle server error from here');
                    });
            },
            componentTypeOnChange(value){
                //console.log(this.componentTypeSelected)
            }
        },
        components: {
            ComponentAddForm,
            SingleBlockTemplate,
            TripleBlockTemplate
        }
    }
</script>
```

I then attempt to call the function from a child element (imported file): **TripleBlockTemplate.vue**

I have tried using just `this.$parent.testAddCompontnet222();` and as you can see below currently `self.$parent.testAddCompontnet222();`

But both return the same error. I have this working in exactly the same way on other components

```
<template>
        <form autocomplete="off" @submit.prevent="addComponent" method="post">
            <b-button @click="testAddCompontnet();">Add Test</b-button>
            <p>This is a triple block component</p>
            <ckeditor :editor="editor" v-model="content[0]" :config="editorConfig"></ckeditor>
            <ckeditor :editor="editor" v-model="content[1]" :config="editorConfig"></ckeditor>
            <ckeditor :editor="editor" v-model="content[2]" :config="editorConfig"></ckeditor>
            <b-button @click="addComponent" variant="outline-primary">Save component</b-button>

        </form>
</template>


<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
export default {
    data(){
        return {<template>
        <form autocomplete="off" @submit.prevent="addComponent" method="post">
            <b-button @click="testAddCompontnet();">Add Test</b-button>
            <p>This is a triple block component</p>
            <ckeditor :editor="editor" v-model="content[0]" :config="editorConfig"></ckeditor>
            <ckeditor :editor="editor" v-model="content[1]" :config="editorConfig"></ckeditor>
            <ckeditor :editor="editor" v-model="content[2]" :config="editorConfig"></ckeditor>
            <b-button @click="addComponent" variant="outline-primary">Save component</b-button>

        </form>
</template>


<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            editor: ClassicEditor,
            name: 'Name here',
            class: 'Class here',
            html_id: 'ID here',
            content:[
                '<div><h1>Title 1</h1><br /><p>some simple text here</p></div>',
                '<div><h1>Title 2</h1><br /><p>some simple text here</p></div>',
                '<div><h1>Title 3</h1><br /><p>some simple text here</p></div>'
            ],
            editorConfig: {
                // The configuration of the editor.
            }
        };
    },
    methods: {
        testAddCompontnet(){
            var self = this;
            self.$parent.testAddCompontnet222();
            console.log("test 222!")
        },
        addComponent(){
            axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: this.$appAPI+'/twg-cms/component',
                data: {
                    name: this.name,
                    content: JSON.stringify({content: this.content}),
                    class: this.class,
                    html_id: this.html_id
                }

            }).then(response => {
                console.log(response.data)
            }).catch(e => {
                console.log(e)
                this.errors.push(e)
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>

            editor: ClassicEditor,
            name: 'Name here',
            class: 'Class here',
            html_id: 'ID here',
            content:[
                '<div><h1>Title 1</h1><br /><p>some simple text here</p></div>',
                '<div><h1>Title 2</h1><br /><p>some simple text here</p></div>',
                '<div><h1>Title 3</h1><br /><p>some simple text here</p></div>'
            ],
            editorConfig: {
                // The configuration of the editor.
            }
        };
    },
    methods: {
        testAddCompontnet(){
            var self = this;
            self.$parent.testAddCompontnet222();
            console.log("test 222!")
        },
        addComponent(){
            axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: this.$appAPI+'/twg-cms/component',
                data: {
                    name: this.name,
                    content: JSON.stringify({content: this.content}),
                    class: this.class,
                    html_id: this.html_id
                }

            }).then(response => {
                console.log(response.data)
            }).catch(e => {
                console.log(e)
                this.errors.push(e)
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Finally here is a working method which i am currently not using...

The following code, would allow me to use the same/similar code to update/change the parent variable `testVar1` to update it's parent: **ComponentAddForm.vue** below

```
        testAddCompontnet(){
            var self = this;
            self.$parent.testVar1 = '11111! test;
            console.log("test 222!")
        },
```

**ComponentAddForm.vue:**

```
<template>
    <b-container>
        testVar1: (( {{ testVar1 }} ))
        <b-button @click="testAddCompontnet222();">Add Test 2</b-button>
        <SingleBlockTemplate v-if="this.componentTemplateId == 1"></SingleBlockTemplate>
        <TripleBlockTemplate v-if="this.componentTemplateId == 2"></TripleBlockTemplate>


    </b-container>
</template>


<script>
import axios from 'axios';

import SingleBlockTemplate from './component_templates/SingleBlockTemplate.vue';
import TripleBlockTemplate from './component_templates/TripleBlockTemplate.vue';

export default {
    props: ['componentTemplateId'],
    data(){
        return {
            name: 'Case Studies',
            testVar1: '1'

        };
    },

    mounted: function () {
        this.showComponentTemplate();
    },

    methods: {
        testAddCompontnet222(){
            this.$parent.testVar2 = '222!';
            console.log("we made it here <--------");
        },
        showComponentTemplate(){
            if(this.componentTemplateId === '1'){
                console.log('test 1')
            }
            if(this.componentTemplateId === '2'){
                console.log('test 2')
            }
        }
    },
    components: {
        SingleBlockTemplate,
        TripleBlockTemplate
    }
}


</script>
```